# Is it possible that test Google Admob Unit id is working but not the real ones?

Tags: admob

I have written the code correctly for showing the AdMob Ads. The test Ads were working but not the real ads. When I added the old Ad unit Id it was working but as soon as I replaced the old unit Id by the new one it stopped working.

I tried a lot to solve it but failed...My dashboard started working partially i.e., Request value started changing but all the other parameters remained the same

Comment: Can you add your code (or a simplified version) and what is not working/any errors you get?